# Product description showing in html

Tags: html, css, magento

I'm having trouble with the desription page for my product. When I click the category link in the Front end to view a product everything works fine. But when I get to the product page and click on the picture or the link for the product it shows the page in HTML. I am new to the magento community, can someone please help me.

Comment: Remember to post comments some code or a link To a page with the problem!

Comment: Its more then likely that a closing tag '>' or similar is missing. @RichBradshaw is right: We cant really help until we see the actual code

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Here is the link. http://www.lightupshoelaces.com/store/index.php/light-up-shoelaces/blue-led-light-up-shoelaces.html

Comment: @MeltingDog Hi Melting, is the code on the page with the link I posted sufficient? Or are you referring to some other code somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

On your home page the following file is loaded:
http://www.lightupshoelaces.com/store/skin/frontend/`default`/default/css/styles.css

Though on your product detailpage the URL differs, which throws a 404.
http://www.lightupshoelaces.com/store/skin/frontend/`base`/default/css/styles.css

This is all I can say at the moment. Did you make any changes to the layout XML files regarding loading of skin files for the catalog product detail page?

Comment: I haven't change anything, I wouldnt know how to anyway. I am a newbie in every sense of the word. I rally do appreciate your advice thus far.

Comment: When you login into the admin and go to the edit page of this specific product. How is the form under the 'Design' tab filled out? Is there a custom design selected?

For now, with the information you provided, it looks like a product configuration issue. Since no other pages have this problem. In the meantime you could also create a second product, place it in this category and leave the design settings untouch. This should give us more information.

Comment: I didn't create a custom design with the first product. I chose blank for the design. I also created another product in the same category and left it untouched as you suggested but it doesn't even show up at all.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked out your site I noticed the homepage linked off to a completely different style sheet then the product page.

The home page links off to style.css which is in the root directory of your site and seems to have the styling you want (e.g. the background image).

The product page has links off to other multiple style sheets but none are the same as your homepage.

Try pasting

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

in the header file of the product pages (sorry I've not used Magento before so I dont know where these file would be...)